# Как получить текущий шаг функции map?

Tags: javascript, массивы, map

Нужно получить текущий шаг функции map.

т.е. Начинается функция map, он достаёт первый элемент, т.е. делает **1** шаг. Вот эту **1** , которая обозначает какой сейчас шаг, мне и нужно получить. Затем он достаёт элемент **2** и эту цифру **2** мне тоже нужно получить. 
Эту цифры мне надо присвоить к свойствам ново-образованного элемента.

```
let arr = [1, 5, 8, 'asdasd', 'blabla']
let newArr = arr.map( n => <input name=nameArr[1].name>);
```

В коде выше `nameArr[1` цифра **1** это наш текущий шаг

Comment: вам нужен индекс элемента массива?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если правильно понял вопрос, то вам нужен индекс элемента массива, получить его можно указав второй аргумент в методе

p.s нумерация элементов массива начинается с 0 (@NeedHate)

```js
let arr = [1, 5, 8, 'asdasd', 'blabla']
let newArr = arr.map((n, i) => <input name=nameArr[i].name>);
```

Comment: Спасибо! То, что нужно! =)

Comment: @ДенисБеспалов Если ответ помог решить вашу задачу, вы можете отметить его галочкой

Comment: Неплохо было бы еще и напомнить, что index начинается с нуля.

Comment: @NeedHate думаю это очевидно, но на всякий случай добавил

Comment: Судя по вопросу - тут нужно )